# How to update PBR textures in python [Blender 2.8]?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I have trillions of PBR textures in a folder. Each group of PBR textures (colormap, normal, etc...) are in their own folder. 
I want to write a python script in Blender that will set up a PBR texture on a standard sphere, render it, and then set up the next PBR etc... 
So I am basically trying to create a catalogue of renders for the textures. This way I can easily understand how does a texture look like on a model.

Currently I can dress the PBR setup to the model. I use `bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled()` for the setup. It is a command from the Node Wrangler. 
But after that, the context changes so the code throws an error when it tries to delete the existing setup (and to add a new setup thereafter). I shared the .blend file.

How can I approach to this problem? How can I reset the context in a way that the code will be able loop through all the PBR textures? Thanks.

My code snippet. Below you can see the functions I am having problems with, and the specific line where it throws the error.

```py
import bpy
import os

# return folders of different texture sites (aka parent dir)
def returnFolders(folder='/home/USERNAME/all_textures/'):
    return  [folder+'/'+i if i[-3:] != '.py' else '' for i in os.listdir(folder)]

# return folder names for each PBR setup (given the parent dir)
def returnTextureFolders(folder=returnFolders()[0]):
    return [folder+'/'+i if i != 'zips' else '' for i in os.listdir(folder)]

# return each texture (given the folders of textures)
def returnTextures(folder=returnTextureFolders()[0]):
    return [texture for texture in os.listdir(folder) if texture[-3:].upper() == 'png'.upper() or texture[-3:].upper() == 'jpg'.upper()]


# I am having problem here
def applyPBR(textures=returnTextures(), mydirectory=returnTextureFolders()[0]):
    bpy.context.area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled(filepath="//../../all_textures/exampletextures.com/" + mydirectory+ "/PBR_TESTER.blend", directory=mydirectory+'/', files=[{"name":texture} for texture in textures], relative_path=True)

# and problem here
def deletePBR():
    bpy.context.area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bpy.ops.node.delete()
    bpy.ops.node.select(wait_to_deselect_others=True, mouse_x=428, mouse_y=279, extend=False, deselect_all=True)


for c, textureFolder in enumerate(returnTextureFolders()):
    if c < 10: # take first 10 texture_folders from the folder of textures
        applyPBR(returnTextures(textureFolder), textureFolder)

    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1) # update the UI
    time.sleep(1) # observe for a second
    deletePBR() ## THROWS AN ERROR HERE (context error)
```

My workaround solution proposal:

1. Set up the PBR setup manually.
2. Using a script, change the source of the image texture nodes in a loop.

Any better ideas? The function I am using automagically understands which texture is color map, specular map... etc. I don't like the idea of making effort to reinvent that magic. There should be an easier way maybe.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Snippet added.

Comment: My workaround solution proposal: (1) set up the PBR setup manually. (2) change the source of the `image texture` nodes in the script.
Any better ideas? The function I am using automagically understand which texture is colormap, specular map... etc... I don't like the idea of making effort to reinvent that magic. There should be an easier way... maybe.